# i don't know what sys.argv is. i don't understand the explanation that was given.

Tags: python

they said it is something like 'executes a command passed on the command line'
but I don't understand, what does it mean by pass on the command line?
can program pass something?

please explain to me what does sys.argv do, and why we need it.
and what sys.argv[1]. does this show directory?

Comment: Who are "they"? Have you tried reading the excellent [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)? It seems you might need to take some time to go through the tutorial.

Comment: I have read that, but I don't understand what ' list of command line arguments passed to a Python script' means. I don't understand how arguments 'pass'.

Comment: How do you execute your python programs?  What arguments do you give it?  Those are the arguments that are passed to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you open a command-line window. In the current directory you have a Python script named `foo.py` looking like this

```
import sys

for argument_index in range(len(sys.argv)):
    print("sys.argv[%d] = %s" % (argument_index, sys.argv[argument_index]))
```

If you run the script like

```
> python foo.py a b c d
```

Then the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are *arguments* to the script. They will be placed in the *list* `sys.argv`. The output of the script will be

```
sys.argv[0] = foo.py
sys.argv[1] = a
sys.argv[2] = b
sys.argv[3] = c
sys.argv[4] = d
```

Comment: so sys.argv is used to change the output from cmd? without changing the code  foo.py?

Comment: @ONLYIFYOUCANREAD No no no. The Python script I show *print* the *contents* of `sys.argv`. It's a way to pass data from the command-line environment when you run the script. Have you *ever* run any program from the command-line? Any at all? Did you run them *with arguments* (the "words" you use after the actual command)? For example `copy from_some_file.txt to_some_other_file.txt`? Those `from_some_file.txt` and `to_some_file.txt` are what will be *passed* ("put in") the argument list.

Comment: @ONLYIFYOUCANREAD If you really don't know anything about "arguments" or the command-line, then stop with Python at once, and go read a basic computer and command-line tutorial.

Comment: oh. so sys.argv passed argument from cmd?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
    
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

You need to execute the script add.py as follows:'python add.py 5 2'
The 'sys. argv[0]' is the name of your script,
so you need to get the second and the third one.

```
print(add(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))
```

**With the command:** 'python add.py 5 10',
this python script will return 15

*sys.argv is a list in Python, which contains the command-line arguments

passed to the script. With the len(sys. argv) function you
can count the number of arguments.*